# Directives for Detecting Clicks outside Element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, addeventlistener, vue-directives

Based on this Article https://medium.com/@Taha_Shashtari/an-easy-way-to-detect-clicks-outside-an-element-in-vue-1b51d43ff634
i implemented the same methodology of the directive for detecting outside element click, at first i had to change things as vue 2 directives have been changed in vue 3, but i got so far that:

1. When i click the Icon to Toggle the Box -> The box is shown
2. When i click outside the Box -> The box is toggled

**The only thing that isn't working is when i click inside the box itself it gets toggled again, which isnt suppose to happen.**

Code

Directive:

```
let handleOutsideClick;
const closable = {
  beforeMount(el, binding, vnode) {
    handleOutsideClick = (e) => {
      e.stopPropagation();
      const { handler, exclude } = binding.value;

      let clickedOnExcludedEl = false;
      exclude.forEach((id) => {
        if (!clickedOnExcludedEl) {
          const excludedEl = document.getElementById(id);
          clickedOnExcludedEl = excludedEl.contains(e.target);
        }
      });

      if (!el.contains(e.target) && !clickedOnExcludedEl) {
        binding.instance[handler]();
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener("click", handleOutsideClick);
    document.addEventListener("touchstart", handleOutsideClick);
  },
  afterMount() {
    document.removeEventListener("click", handleOutsideClick);
    document.removeEventListener("touchstart", handleOutsideClick);
  },
};

export default closable;
```

PS: I changed the usage of refs into IDs

CartIcon:

```
<template>
  <div
    id="checkoutBoxHandler"
    ref="checkoutBoxHandler"
    @click="showPopup = !showPopup"
    class="cart-icon"
  >
    <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping" />
    <span id="cart-summary-item">{{ cartItemsCount }}</span>
    <div
      v-show="showPopup"
      v-closable='{
        exclude: ["checkoutBox","checkoutBoxHandler"],
        handler: "onClose",
      }'
      id="checkoutBox"
    >
      <CheckOutBox   v-if="this.userCart" :userCart="this.userCart"></CheckOutBox>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

onClose handler:

```
 onClose() {
      this.showPopup = false;
    },
```

Can anyone see what i might be doing wrong here or maybe missing?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT after Turtle Answers:**

This is the Code i m using:

Directive:

```
const clickedOutsideDirective = {
  mounted(element, binding) {
    
    const clickEventHandler = (event) => {
      event.stopPropagation();
      console.log(element.contains(event.target))//True on click on the box
      if (!element.contains(event.target)) {
        binding.value(event)
      }
    }
    element.__clickedOutsideHandler__ = clickEventHandler
    document.addEventListener("click", clickEventHandler)
  },
  unmounted(element) {
    document.removeEventListener("click", element.__clickedOutsideHandler__)
  },
}

export default clickedOutsideDirective
```

Component:

```
<div
    id="checkoutBoxHandler"
    ref="checkoutBoxHandler"
    @click="showPopup = !showPopup"
    v-closable='onClose'
    class="cart-icon"
  >
    <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping" />
    <span id="cart-summary-item">{{ cartItemsCount }}</span>
    <div
      v-show="showPopup"
      
      ref="checkoutBox"
      id="checkoutBox"
    >
      <CheckOutBox :userCart="this.userCart"></CheckOutBox>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The box is being displayed but on click on the box it still disappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem could be multiple registered event listeners.

`afterMount` should be `unmounted`. If fixing that isn't enough, you may need to ensure you're unregistering the event correctly. You can store the handler on the element like this:

```js
const closable = {
  beforeMount(el, binding, vnode) {
    el.__handleOutsideClick__ = (e) => {
      e.stopPropagation();
      const { handler, exclude } = binding.value;

      let clickedOnExcludedEl = false;
      exclude.forEach((id) => {
        if (!clickedOnExcludedEl) {
          const excludedEl = document.getElementById(id);
          clickedOnExcludedEl = excludedEl.contains(e.target);
        }
      });

      if (!el.contains(e.target) && !clickedOnExcludedEl) {
        binding.instance[handler]();
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener("click", el.__handleOutsideClick__);
    document.addEventListener("touchstart", el.__handleOutsideClick__);
  },
  // The correct lifecycle method is 'unmounted'
  unmounted(el) {
    document.removeEventListener("click", el.__handleOutsideClick__);
    document.removeEventListener("touchstart", el.__handleOutsideClick__);
  },
};

export default closable;
```

### Other advice

- Don't call stopPropagation on the event, because it could swallow clicks on other UI elements.
- Forward the event when invoking the handler so that the handler can inspect it.

To ensure your directive doesn't break, you probably don't want to reference the excluded nodes by ID, but rather by ref as in the article you linked.

Or, drop the exclusions feature altogether. Without it, your directive can look like below. It looks like you're only using it to exclude things that are already inside your popup. In my experience, clicked outside should mean clicked outside. If there are additional considerations, I would prefer to let the handler take care of them by inspecting the returned event.

```js
import { Directive } from 'vue'

// Trigger a function when a click is registered outside the element
const clickedOutsideDirective = {
  mounted(element, binding) {
    const clickEventHandler = (event) => {
      if (!element.contains(event.target)) {
        binding.value(event)
      }
    }
    element.__clickedOutsideHandler__ = clickEventHandler
    document.addEventListener("click", clickEventHandler)
  },
  unmounted(element) {
    document.removeEventListener("click", element.__clickedOutsideHandler__)
  },
}

export default clickedOutsideDirective
```

Now the usage looks like this

```
<template>
  <div
    id="checkoutBoxHandler"
    ref="checkoutBoxHandler"
    @click="showPopup = !showPopup"
    class="cart-icon"
  >
    <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping" />
    <span id="cart-summary-item">{{ cartItemsCount }}</span>
    <div
      v-show="showPopup"
      v-clicked-outside='onClose'
      id="checkoutBox"
    >
      <CheckOutBox   v-if="this.userCart" :userCart="this.userCart"></CheckOutBox>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I did try changing the afterMount to unmounted, didn't work.
Changed the Exluding function to Refs instead of Ids still was doing the same as you click on the Box it disappear.
After  a bit of changes, i tried taking the whole excluding out but i came across other Problem, that the Box didnt show at all, because the icon where you d click is outside the Box and therefor the event listner recalls the onClose handler : i could see it on the console it prints out console.log("pop up " + this.showPopup) true and false straight away

Comment: You should be able to trap the initial trigger event by calling event.stopPropagation in its handler (when the user clicks the trigger button) to avoid it bubbling up and setting off the directive.

Comment: Looking at your template, it looks like you can also just move the directive up to the outer div.

Comment: Sorry, i was mistaken, i had a different console.log on the directive that was given the false, but i tried again with taking the directive up to the outer Div, which resulted in the box being shown but when you click the box it vanishes again, can you please elaborate on what the binding.value(event) does, somehow i feel on that line something isnt happening

Comment: Now it works, i changed the @click to the Icon instead of the outer Div and keeping the directive assignment to the outer Div, now it works like a charm, thanks (y)

Comment: I'm glad it works! What ever is passed to the directive is `binding.value`. Since we're passing a function (onClose in your case), we can call it like `binding.value(event)`.

Answer (score 0):

For me the best solution for this problem is to create some object in the background.

```
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
z-index: check which value fits you here.
```

So at beginning before showing "box" that object do not exist. On box show, you also show that object which is in background, above all elements except your "box".

So only thing you can click outside of your "box" is that object. And you can put event on "that object click".

And on box hide, you also hide that object;

Comment: This seems like a reasonable solution, but i have multiple boxs and icons where i would need to listen to the clicks, that s why the directives were the ideal way to go, i already implemented it correctly and worked with vuex  Store, the problem was that i needed to put the same code on each View which wasn't ideal, thanks for the suggestion though